# How debug an Android application SIGSEGV with no back trace in logcat and no data/tombstone?

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, native

An android app is crashing continuously on emulators because of SIGSEGV that are not obvious. The problem is that there is :

- nothing in the logcat (whatever the filter, there are always nothing).
- no /data/tombstone folder on the emulator (how is it even possible ?)

I know about ndk-stack, but I need a backtrace for that. I have read all the Android documentation and everything I could on the subject, I found NOTHING. The closest I found is [this documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash) about "Low-address null pointer dereference", but obviously without backtrace it is very hard to diagnostic.

Comment: If there's nothing in the log and no tombstone how do you know it's crashing? When apps crash in native code is does show up in logcat and should also create a dropbox entry for the crash. SIGSEGV just means an invalid memory reference so the cause could be anything.

Comment: Why don't you write an app that causes a SIGSEGV purposefully and see what happens on the emulator, see if it matches what you think you are seeing when your app crashes?

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyBlattman, simple advice and yet I absolutely did not though about it. Anyway it was indeed a SIGSEGV because a ```calloc()``` was not responded by a ```free()``` later. The SIGSEGV problem is solved, but the empty back trace has not been resolved yet.

Comment: @Jeffrey Blattman: that one is easy: because the single error line *is* in logcat. The backtrace and all the other details associated with the tombstone are not. I have the same problem right now, for instance, and logcat itself clearly states: "E/DEBUG: Failed to find a valid tombstone".